# Code to find indexes of array that are in prime number position and replace the array element with -1 in Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, methods

I'm new to programming and I have a task to do but I'm struggling and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've tried many different methods and made alterations to try and make it work but I just can't figure it out.

I have an array of 200, each one filled with the number 10 using `Arrays.fill` and I need to have it so that all numbers in the position of a prime number are to be replaced with -1 and the array printed out. e.g. 10 -1 -1 10 -1 10... etc.

This is what I have right now -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] test = new int[200];
    Arrays.fill(test, 10);

    print(numbers);
    System.out.println();
    print(primeReplace(test));


}

public static void print(int[] a) {
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    }
}

public static int[] primeReplace(int[] a) {

    System.out.println("Prime: ");

    for(int i = 1; i < a.length; i++)
    {
            if(isPrime(i))
            {
                a[i] = -1;
            }
    }
    return a;

}

public static boolean isPrime(int b) {

    for(int i = 2; i < b; i++)
    {
        if (b % i == 0) 
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Which returns `-1 -1 -1 -1 10 -1 10 -1 10 10 10 -1 10 -1 10 10 10 -1 10...` etc.

I've also tried just this -

```
public static int[] primeReplace(int[] a) {

    System.out.println("Prime: ");

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 2; j < i; j++)
        {
            if(i % j == 0)
            {
                a[i] = -1;
            }
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Which returns: `10 10 10 10 -1 10 -1 10 -1 -1 -1 10 -1 10... etc.`

I'm probably missing something really simple as I'm no good at maths, but it's driving me crazy and I just don't understand it so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `10 -1 -1 10 -1 10` ?? array index starts with `0`.

Comment: Hint: a prime number is a number **greater than one** that is divisible by any number **other than 1 or itself**.

Comment: Besides the `print(numbers)` couldn't see anything wrong with the code... I think that the `for` on primeReplace should start at 0 and in the isPrime the if should be `if (b % i == 0 && b !=0) ` [since 0 is not considered a prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539174/is-zero-a-prime-number)

Comment: @JorgeCampos - neither is one!  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number  and https://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/one.html.   Chloe13's implementation of isPrime returns true for `1`.

Comment: @StephenC yeah, you are right then it should be `... && b>1` Thank you pointing that out :)

Comment: This assignment seems to suggest to use the sieve of Eratosthenes for finding the primes.

Comment: In general you should beware of writing `isPrime()` methods. It is horrifically inefficient, by definition, to test every integer in your range for primeness. Instead you should be looking to *generate* the primes in the range sequentially, using whatever version of the Sieve of Eratosthenes suits you, and do what you need to do with each prime as it arises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code for your answer.

```
public class PrimeDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] test = new int[200];
    Arrays.fill(test, 10);

   // print(numbers);
    System.out.println();
    print(primeReplace(test));


}

public static void print(int[] a) {
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    }
}

public static int[] primeReplace(int[] a) {

    System.out.println("Prime: ");

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
            if(isPrime(i))
            {
                a[i] = -1;
            }
    }
    return a;

}

private static boolean isPrime(int a) {
    if (a< 2) return false;
    if (a== 2) return true;
    if (a% 2 == 0) return false;
    for (int i = 3; i * i <= a; i += 2)
        if (a % i == 0) return false;
    return true;
}
}
```

I am just change your isPrime method.Prime Number always start from 2 and array index start from 0.

and Output looks like

Prime: 
10 10 -1 -1 10 -1 10 -1 10 10 10 -1 10 -1 10 10 10 -1 10 -1 10 10 10 -1 10 10 10 10 10 -1 10 -1 10 10 10 10 10 -1 10 10 10 -1 10 -1 10 10 10 -1 10 10 10 10 10 -1 10 10 10 10 10 -1 10 -1 10 10 10 10 10 -1 10 10 10 -1 10 -1 10 10 10 10 10 -1 10 10 10 -1 10 10 10 10 10 -1 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 -1 10 10 10 -1 10 -1 10 10 10 -1 10 -1 10 10 10 -1 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 -1 10 10 10 -1 10 10 10 10 10 -1 10 -1 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 -1 10 -1 10 10 10 10 10 -1 10 10 10 10 10 -1 10 10 10 -1 10 10 10 10 10 -1 10 10 10 10 10 -1 10 -1 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 -1 10 -1 10 10 10 -1 10 -1

Answer (score 0):

use this method:

```
public boolean isPrimeNumber(int num) {
        int factors = 0;
        int j = 1;

        while(j <= num)
        {
            if(num % j == 0)
            {
                factors++;
            }
            j++;
        }
        return (factors == 2);
  }
```

or this method:

```
private static boolean isPrime(int num) {
        if (num < 2) return false;
        if (num == 2) return true;
        if (num % 2 == 0) return false;
        for (int i = 3; i * i <= num; i += 2)
            if (num % i == 0) return false;
        return true;
}
```